# How to extract files from a split 7zip archive?

Tags: file-format, archive, compression, 7zip

I downloaded a series of packages that all compress one thing. The files end in `.0`, `.1`, `.2`, etc.

The User Lists of these packages I downloaded say to use the `file.bat` to successfully extract, or to use 7zip. I do not understand how to do that with 7zip.

Comment: mmmmm... nope, the files are named "asdf.iso.0" etc. and in the menu I cant see "Extract Here" :/

Comment: If you don't see Extract Here in the popup menu - please try the command-line solution from the answer below

Answer (score 41):

**Install 7zip from the Ubuntu Software Center.**

[image: Install via the software center]

**Command-line solution:**

In terminal, `cd` to the directory that contains the volumes and run `7z` command on the first file from the sequence:

```
cd ~/Downloads
7z x asdf.iso.0
```

`7zip` should notice that you have a multi-volume archive and unpack everything. If you want the directory structure flattened, use `7z e` instead of `7z x`.

**GUI Solution**

- Right-click the first package of those you downloaded (eg `file.zip.001`).
- Select "Extract Here".

Comment: I think 7z does automatically detect split volumes/archives.  Not sure about the other answer requiring a split flag.  My only problem was that I needed to change my working directly, which actually fits this example better.  That detail simply was not highlighted.  Did this on Windows with the `7z` CLI on a `...7z.###` archive format.

Answer (score 20):

Using 7zip to extract iso file is extremely simple even it has multiple parts.
Let's assume you have an iso archive with three parts named by **a.iso.001**, **a.iso.002**, **a.iso.003**.

The standard command line is in this way:

```
7z x a.iso.001 -tiso.split -o<output_dir>
```

or

```
7z x a.iso.001 -tudf.split -o<output_dir>
```

Passing the **-t** flag with the **"split"** indication will specifically tell 7z that the iso has multi-parts, the preceding **"iso"** or **"udf"** will depend on your iso container format.

Comment: `-tsplit` (only) did the trick for me - thanks! It would have been "*extremely simple*" if 7zip would recognize its own (!) split archives  and not force users into diving into the subtleties of additional cmdline parameters. I remember older archivers who were easily capable of that. *shrug*

Comment: didn't need the -tsplit command, just making sure that filenames are equal is important! So if i have 3 files, 'archive.rar.001 archive.rar.002 archive.rar.003' I can extract it as follows: $ 7z x archive.rar.001

Answer (score 2):

Install 7zip, if its not installed, using this command:

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

Now move to directory which contains split files and run this:

```
7z e file.ova.7z.1
```